# Are there any Android devices in the US market or elsewhere that do NOT ship with the Google Maps Add-On library?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have heard that the ARCHOS 5 Internet Tablet doesn't have the Google APIs SDK, but rather the plain vanilla Android 1.6 OS build.  Is this true?  And does anyone know of any other devices like this currently on the market or in the works?

I'm particularly interested in phones, but would like to know about any such devices.  My company adds maps to our apps but they are often optional, so I'd like to know if I need to be worried that these apps won't be available to non-maps devices.

Comment: Why worry about crappy devices? That shouldn't be developer's problem

Comment: While devices with/without the Maps library will be debatable, I'm going to go out on a limb and say if you're selling through the Market, a device with Market support will have Maps support. However, you definitely need to program around the fact that it may not be supported, just as you would with other hardware features.

Comment: First of all, you're not helping ognian.

Second of all, couldn't you two have posted an _answer_ rather than a _comment?_

Third, I doubt your assumption is correct, Andrew.  Google makes us put the `<uses-library>` tag in our manifest for a reason, so that the Market can filter out apps that are not compatible with the device.  See here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

It's true that ARCHOS uses something else called AppsLib, but I don't think that precludes the possibility of another device doing it.

Comment: Also, if you read the "Android Compatibility Definition Document" available [here](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html), nowhere does it require Android Compatible devices to have either Google Maps or Android Market.  I may want to sell my app through other venues in the future.

Comment: I was aware of the <uses-library/> tag, but that does nothing for optional resources. If you want Maps to be optional, you have to program around it.

Comment: Yes, true, I will have to program around it, if I want to support non-maps devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of Android-based tablets out there (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices). The link doesn't have information as to whether or not they have Google apps installed, but if you do some research, you can find more info. The 1&1 Smartpad for example doesn't seem to have proprietary Google apps (I don't see any on the screenshots: http://www.slashgear.com/11-smartpad-android-tablet-drops-in-germany-3092321/).

Now the thing to keep in mind is that if a device doesn't have Google Maps, it *probably* doesn't have Market either. (To go back to the 1&1 example, I see a "1&1 Market" app on the screenshots).

Your best bet may be to provide your app on all known major app sites (http://www.andappstore.com, etc) and even your company's website in addition to the Google Market to maximize exposure. Al Sutton's andappstore in particular is a popular site for people with Android-based devices that don't have the market.